# What plist settings should I use to share documents in iOS8

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm trying to share a document using SLComposeServiceViewController in iOS, the document I'm testing this out with is a pdf (though I need the ability to share any file). 
I send my PDF to Mail on the iPhone, press and hold on the attachment, but my icon never shows. 
I have image, URL and Text share working fine, I just can't seem to get any type of document to work.

I'm assuming NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount and/or NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount need to be set, but I have no idea what the difference is between them.

This is my plist at the moment...

Can anyone help?

```html
<key>NSExtension</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
   <dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMinCount</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsVideoWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
   </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
  <string>MainInterface</string>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
 </dict>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are predicates and all of them have to be satisfied for your extension to be shown. You probably only need *NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMinCount* like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMinCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointName</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointVersion</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
    </dict>
```

Test using just [TRUEPREDICATE](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) to make sure the predicates are really the cause of the problem.

One more thing: share extensions are not enabled by default, so make sure you check the More [...] button at the end of the list of share targets.

Answer (score 0):

You can get files from Mail (or similar) and Dropbox (Box, iCloud or similar) with this code in your extension info.plist

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```